# Batch script to map between 2 locations

Tags: windows, batch-file, drive-mapping

So I map a drive to T \server01\tfolder

I need a script which does the following

If T is mapped to \server01\tfolder then map it to server02\tolder. But if drive is mapped to \server02\tfolder then map it to \server01\tfolder

I am using an else switch but already but can't for the life of me work out how I get it to confirm which its being mapped to already and then map it to the alternate.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

```
for /f "tokens=2" %%a in ('net use t: ^|find "\\"') do set "current=%%a"
if "%current%" == "\\server01\tfolder" (
  set "new=\\server02\tfolder"
) else (
  set "new=\\server01\tfolder"
)
echo switching from %current% to %new%
```